# Integrating SVN with kwallet

Tags: svn, kde-plasma

I can't for my life make SVN read the password stored at kwallet and use it to stop asking when I do anything. Google has not helped finding the answer, so I turn back to you.

I'm running right now Kubuntu 16.04 fully upgraded, SVN is version 1.9.3 (r1718519), and it says that it has support for KWALLET

The following authentication credential caches are available:

```
* Plaintext cache in /home/ssol/.subversion
* Gnome Keyring
* GPG-Agent
* KWallet (KDE)
```

My `.subversion/config` has the following configuration:

```
[auth]
password-stores = kwallet
```

My `.subversion/servers` has the following configuration:

```
[global]
store-passwords = yes
```

KWallet is installed, the Wallet manager says Version 15.12.3. I only have 1 wallet, the default `kdewallet` with a bunch of folders there. I know it works because I use it with `ksshaskpass` and it works flawless. On Subversion, something is not working right.

After I added the configurations, I did an svn update on a project I have, it asked for the password. After typing it, the annexed prompt popped, to allow subversion to connect to the wallet. I type the wallet password and allowed it. But no entry was update inside the wallet.

I tried a second type, it asked again for the same prompt. And, this time, SVN saved the password as a **plain-text inside the .subversion/auth/svn.simple/**.

So, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have libsvn_auth_kwallet-1-0 installed.

Comment: Please don't write answers in a way that makes them look like questions.
There are systems in place to check for Not An Answer (NAA) posts.
This answer was falsely picked up by one of them. Please consider editing it to look more like an answer. Rephase the "Do you have libsvn_auth_kwallet-1-0 installed?" part.