# Permanently authorize Subversion to open KWallet

Tags: svn, kde-plasma

This question is a followup to another one I asked 6 months ago ([Integrating SVN with kwallet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38000624/integrating-svn-with-kwallet)) but it is different now.

I manage to make SVN integrate with KWallet, but now, everytime I do an svn command it popups asking for authorization to access the KWallet. Is it possible to five a permanent authorization? So that it doesn't ask me to open the wallet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After sometime I found the solution. Just need to add a Subversion entry on the default wallet